Eclipse Git Synchronize View shows identical files as conflicting
In the Synchronize View (newest Eclipse 2024-03, Git Integration for Eclipse 6.9.0) I see many files listed and marked as Conflicting that are identical. This makes it impossible to see at a glance what files differ between two branches. To find out what files really differ one would have to click each file separately and check if the status is green or not.
I can reproduce this always:

fresh clone a GIT repo with initial checkout of origin/main,
import it as maven project,
run Compare With... and choose branch origin/XXX,
the Synchronize View which opens shows many files marked as Conflicting that are identical.

Further analysis:

the same happens when I checkout origin/XXX as new branch, run Compare With... and choose branch XXX.
all files are binary identical (I checked that with a external hex editor as well as git diff HEAD..XXX).
I also tried all the Ignore Whitespace options I found in the preferences but that made no difference.

What could cause this problem, and how can it be solved?

2024-06 isn't actually released yet - Release Candidate 2 only just became available - are you running the most current pre-release code?

Thank you for the hint, I corrected the version to 2024-03. But the problem occurred also in previous versions...
